# Lightning Layout Item Styling Not Consistent

Tags: css, lightning-layouts

This is not making sense to me:
I have a simple style declared in the component's css file:

```
.targetcolor  {
    background-color: #bff0ff;
}
```

Which I reference like this:

```
<lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_x-small targetcolor"  key={sd.Id} size="6" large-device-size="3">
<strong>My Simple Label</strong>
 </lightning-layout-item>
 <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_x-small targetcolor"  key={sd.Id} size="6" large-device-size="3">
<strong>{MySimpleValue}</strong>
 </lightning-layout-item>
```

This normally works, unless:
The label wraps to a second line, in which case the background on the line that appears below the value to align with the wrapped label is now white
The value is empty - and again, the background value is white

Bit if I have layout item with size="12", with a blank value, the background does respect the CSS:

```
<lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_x-small targetcolor"  key={sd.Id} size="12" large-device-size="3">
<strong>{MyEmptySimpleValue}</strong>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

How do I get the background in the Layout Item to always use the CSS color in the class?

Comment: Is your layout vertical aligned ?

Comment: Adding - `vertical-align="stretch"` to the parent `lightning-layout` will solve this issue. Optionally , you can add `multiple-rows="true"` as well.

Comment: Thanks - vertical-align="stretch"  did the trick (multiple rows didn't seem to be enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the solution from the comments section.

Using `vertical-align="stretch"` to the parent `lightning-layout` will help in wrapping the background along with the text.

More info - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout/example